# AMCharts - setting the label of the Y axis

Tags: amcharts

Im just wondering how I can do this. I set up a grid and I give it the following options:

```
this._chartOptions = 
{
    "type": 'serial',
    "categoryField": "category",
    "balloonText": '',
    "startDuration": 1,
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start"
    },
    "trendLines": [],
    "graphs": [
        {
            "balloonColor": "#ffff00",
            "colorField": "#ffff00",
            "fillAlphas": 1,
            "fillColors": "#ffff00",
            "id": "AmGraph-1",
            "lineColorField": "ffff00",
            "title": "graph 1",
            "type": "column",
            "valueField": "column-1"
        },                  
    ],
    "guides": [],
    "valueAxes": [
        {
            "id": "ValueAxis-1",
            "title": 'Deals per stage'
        }
    ],
    "allLabels": [],
    "balloon": {},
    "titles": [],
    "dataProvider": this._dataProvider
}
```

Then I have some buttons. The buttons change the chart being displayed. So by default it shows a bar chart and then the next button will display that info as a pie chart. The next one is supposed to show a different bar chart. 
My problem is that I cant seem to change the y axis label. By default it is  'Deals per stage'. When I open up this bar chart I want to change it to 'Revenue per Quarter'.

Ive tried setting the following when the button is clicked:

```
__this._chartOptions.valueAxes = [
{
    "id": "ValueAxis-1",
    "title": 'Revenue per Quarter'
}];
```

But this ends up causing the bars in the bar chart not to draw for some reason. IS there an easy way to do this? Can anyone tell me why the above would stop the data drawing in the chart?

Comment: How are you redrawing the chart? `validateNow()`? `validateData()`? Why not just set the title element directly instead of creating a brand new array? (`__this._chartOptions.valueAxes[0].title = "..."`). Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: That worked. It seems other stuff is set there and i was over writing it when replacing the whole property. 
As for how I draw it, Ive just started with this so right now I am clearing the div and just calling makeChart again

Comment: Yeah, don't do that. Use `validateData()` or `validateNow()` to redraw after changing properties or data. Clearing the div doesn't free up memory taken up by the chart and will lead to other visual bugs down the line as old instances will still think they're active and try to take over. If you need to replace a div with a completely different chart type or just outright delete it, call the chart's `clear` method to clean up the chart.

Comment: Hmmmm. I think for what I will be doing just clearing it out completely will be the better option.  Cheers for the info.

Comment: @xorspark: Hey, not sure you are using it but do you know for am charts 4 what is the preferred method for doing this? There is no clear function, Im reading through a bunch of documentation but I dont see it saying what I should do when changing from one chart type to another

Comment: It's called [`dispose`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/chart/#dispose_method) in v4.

Comment: Thats the one. Thanks again

Comment: Hey. In order to redraw in version 4 what is the method I call?

Comment: You generally don't need to force a redraw as the chart detects the majority of changes on its own, except in some cases (usually data oriented). If you need to force a redraw, [`invalidate`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/container/#invalidate_method), `invalidateData`, or [`invalidateRawData`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/component/#invalidateRawData_method) depending on your needs. The latter two are primarily focused around [data updates](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Dynamic_updates).